# Can't stop Clamav deamon in Linux

Tags: clam, clamav

I am trying to stop Clamav service in Linux, but I am not able to do that.
I have installed Clamav in a seperate directory.

When running below command:

```
$ systemctl stop clamav-daemon
```

I get this error message:

> Warning: Stopping clamav-daemon.service, but it can still be activated by:
>     clamav-daemon.socket

When running:

```
$ systemctl status clamav-daemon
```

I get:

```
 clamav-daemon.service - Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-04-29 13:23:33 IST; 7s ago
     Docs: man:clamd(8)
           man:clamd.conf(5)
           https://www.clamav.net/documents/
 Main PID: 32213 (clamd)
    Tasks: 1
   CGroup: /system.slice/clamav-daemon.service
           └─32213 /usr/local/sbin/clamd --foreground=true
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you are logged in as a normal user which can be understood by seeing the $ sign in your command, clamav won't stop. You need to perform the following command.

It will stop clamav for only logged-in session

```
$ sudo systemctl stop clamav-daemon
```

To see the status

```
$ sudo systemctl status clamav-daemon
```

It will return:

```
● clamav-daemon.service - Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/clamav-daemon.service.d
             └─extend.conf
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:clamd(8)
             man:clamd.conf(5)
             https://www.clamav.net/documents/

Aug 20 08:58:53 machine clamd[808]: Thu Aug 20 08:58:53 2020 -> HTML support enabled.
Aug 20 08:58:53 machine clamd[808]: Thu Aug 20 08:58:53 2020 -> XMLDOCS support enabled.
Aug 20 08:58:53 machine clamd[808]: Thu Aug 20 08:58:53 2020 -> HWP3 support enabled.
Aug 20 08:58:53 machine clamd[808]: Thu Aug 20 08:58:53 2020 -> Self checking every 3600 seconds.
Aug 20 09:58:53 machine clamd[808]: Thu Aug 20 09:58:53 2020 -> SelfCheck: Database status OK.
Aug 20 10:57:51 machine systemd[1]: Stopping Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon...
Aug 20 10:57:52 machine clamd[808]: Thu Aug 20 10:57:52 2020 -> --- Stopped at Thu Aug 20 10:57:52 >
Aug 20 10:57:52 machine clamd[808]: Thu Aug 20 10:57:52 2020 -> Socket file removed.
Aug 20 10:57:52 machine systemd[1]: clamav-daemon.service: Succeeded.
Aug 20 10:57:52 machine systemd[1]: Stopped Clam AntiVirus userspace daemon.
```

If you have created symbolic link of clamav daemon to start the program automatically when pc boot then you need to remove that link so that clamav shouldn't start automatically

```
$ sudo systemctl disable clamav-daemon
```